# Prove by induction the formula for n-step transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Prove by induction that $(Y_n)_{n\ge0}$ is:
$\frac1 2$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{2^{n-1}+1} {2^n} & 1 & \frac{2^{n-1}-1} {2^n}\\\frac1 2 & 1 & \frac 1 2 \\ \frac{2^{n-1}-1} {2^n} & 1 & \frac{2^{n-1}+1} {2^n}\end{bmatrix}$
is the n-step matrix for
$Y_0$:
$\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5 & 0\\ 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.25 \\ 0 & 0.5 & 0.5\end{bmatrix}$

I think $(Y_n)_{n\ge0}$ is wrong because if you set $n=0$ you get negative values for the top right and bottom left index, which you can't have a stochastic matrix.

Comment: Technically you should have the transition matrix be $Y_1$ and $Y_0$ be the identity matrix. Because for any matrix $A$, $A^0$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: I see that seems weird though since is says $n \ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ Y_1 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Assume for some $n\geqslant 1$ that
$$
Y_n = \frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2^{-n}+\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-n}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 2^{-n}-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
Y_{n+1} &= Y_1Y_n\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2^{-n}+\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-n}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 2^{-n}-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2^{-(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 2^{-(n+1)}-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 2^{-(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{align}
so by induction the claim holds for all $n\geqslant 1$.